# Make a list with the result from a sql query in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to make a list with the results from a SQL query in Python.

After execution of:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
result_list = [row for row in rows]
print result_list
```

I am getting output as: `[('a',),('b',),('c',)]`

I need the output as: `['a','b','c']`

Answer (score 5):

The result list contains tupels with one element. You have to get this element out of each tupel:

```
result = [row[0] for row in rows]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
rows = cursor.fetchall()
result_list = list(itertools.chain(*rows))
```

This works even when each row contains more than one element.

For example, if `rows = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`, this will produce
`['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]`

Answer (score 0):

The above did not work for me. My solution to it was the following.

```
list_res = []
for row in rows:
    list_res.append(str(row[0]))
```

Answer (score -1):

For python 3 I have simple solution:

```
sql_data = cursor.fetchall()
python_list = []
for row in sql_data:
    python_list.append(row)
refactor_from_sql_to_list = [list(i) for i in sql_list]
final_list = sum(refactor_from_sql_to_list, [])
```